# push object to another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array like this

```
var assets = [
    {
    "name": "male",
    "type": [
        {
          name: "tommy",
          y: 512,
        },
        {
          name: "rian",
          y: 812,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
    "name": "female",
    "type": [
        {
          name: "mariam",
          y: 512,
        },
        {
          name: "linda",
          y: 412,
        },
      ],
    }
  ];
```

and have a button with same title same as their object's name

```
<button title="male">this is male</button>
<button title="female">this is female</button>
```

when i click one of them i want to push the object base of the clicked button to another array

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var attr= $(this).attr('title');
    var obj = assets.find(function (obj) { return obj.name === attr; });
    data =[];
    data.push(obj.type);
    console.log(data);    
  });
```

i got an output like this

```
[Array(2)]
    0:Array(2)
      0:{name: "mariam", y: 512}
      1:{name: "linda", y: 412}
      length:2
      __proto__: Array(0)
      length:1
    __proto__:  Array(0)
```

how to change it to become like this

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:{name: "mariam", y: 512}
  1:{name: "linda", y: 412}
  length:2
  __proto__:Array(0)
```

[link here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzbPqV)

Comment: Get rid of `data  = []` and `data.push(...)`. Just use `obj.type` directly as that's already in the format you want.

Comment: so how to push to another array?

Comment: In that case you can use `push()` - but why do you need to? The data is already in the format your question requires - as you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/soen254n/

Answer (score 0):

**If another array `data`(in this case) is empty**

You can directly assign like below.

```js
var assets=[{"name":"male","type":[{name:"tommy",y:512,},{name:"rian",y:812,},],},{"name":"female","type":[{name:"mariam",y:512,},{name:"linda",y:412,},],}]

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var attr= $(this).attr('title');
    var obj = assets.find(function (obj) { return obj.name === attr; });
    data =obj.type;
    console.log(data);    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button title="male">this is male</button>
<button title="female">this is female</button>
```

**If another array `data`(in this case) is non-empty**

You can use **`Array.concat`**.

```js
var assets=[{"name":"male","type":[{name:"tommy",y:512,},{name:"rian",y:812,},],},{"name":"female","type":[{name:"mariam",y:512,},{name:"linda",y:412,},],}]

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var attr= $(this).attr('title');
    var obj = assets.find(function (obj) { return obj.name === attr; });
    data =[];   
    data=data.concat(obj.type); // use concat which will also work if data array is not empty
    console.log(data);    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button title="male">this is male</button>
<button title="female">this is female</button>
```

Comment: Why use `concat` with an empty array? It's the same as just `data = obj.type;`

Comment: Here it empty array, but in case if array is not empty, then we can't directly assign like you said.(I just give solution which will in both case)@Barmar

Comment: he just wants the list from the object, nothing in the question suggests that it should be added to anything that already exists.

Comment: Title is 'push object to another array', he has not said that whether another array is empty or not. So used concat. But I am agree with you that if another array is empty then concat make no sense.@Barmar

Comment: His code has `data =[];` in it, so the array is initially empty.